# Ajax loaded data doesn't update layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I load data using ajax and populate my page using Knockout. This all works great, when I changes pages to `#contacts` it looks good. However, I have a problem when the #contacts page is the initial page i load. E.g. if I load `www.mydomain.com/#contacts`, the initial page loaded is the list page, thus the `ko.bindinghandlers.listview` doesn't have any affect. I tried re-creating the page, but that doesn't fully work either, not all the styles are applied as it should. My list view is not just a list view, it contains a controllgroup as well, to make a list view with checkboxes.

```
$("#contacts").page('destroy').page();

$('#contacts').bind('pageinit', function() {
    $('ul').listview();
});
```

How can I load data using Ajax, append it (using ko) to my `ul` and have it render correctly.

This is how it looks if `#contacts` is NOT the initial page loaded:
[image: Correct]

This is the best result I manage to get this far, when `#contacts` IS the initial page loaded:
[image: Incorrect]

Comment: I’m just guessing, but maybe bind the handler *before* calling `.page()`?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question?

Comment: @David no difference. Same result

Comment: @UriAbramson Updated it now. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: try this `$('#contacts').on('pagebeforeshow', function () { $('ul').listview().trigger('create'); });` dont use `.bind` use `.on` - http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Xcdwt/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that both before and after the `page('destroy')` and before and after `page()`, but I get the same results.

Comment: After logging to the console, the code does not seem to be run

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `refresh` on your listview whenever your update it using JavaScript.

`$('.selector').listview('refresh');`

More on the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/lists/lists-methods.html).

Comment: I tried that, however it doesn't render it correctly. e.g. class tag is not added to a h3 tag, which is it if the #contacts page is not the initial page.

Answer (score 0):

pageinit() probably doesn't get called when its the first load.
add a console.info there to make sure... if that's the issue, then just make sure it is being called on load() or whenever you feel like it. was that it?